# Проблема с поиском в строке

Tags: python, python-3.x, find

Задание с сайта на английском. Я не могу понять, чего они от меня хотят(((

Задача:

Прочтите ввод, найдите начальный индекс **старой** подстроки , затем выполните поиск в обратном направлении от конца строки для той же подстроки и выведите большее значение из двух.

Та же задача на английском (вдруг его как-то знает лучше меня и в оригинале есть больше смысла):

Read the input, find the starting index of the substring **old**, then search backward from the end of the string for the same substring, and print the bigger value of the two.

Код. Что-то с ним не так в начале.

```
string = str(input())
starting_index = str(input())
starting_index_find = string.find(starting_index)
starting_index_rfind = string.rfind(starting_index)
if string.find(starting_index) > string.rfind(starting_index):
    print(starting_index_find)
else:
    print(starting_index_rfind)
```

Comment: не старой подстроки, а подстроки "old"

Comment: Помогло))) Дурацкий английский, придется все-таки начинать его учить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

немного короче:

```
string = input()
print(max(string.find('old'), string.rfind('old')))
```

Answer (score 1):

Вариант 2:

```
string = str(input())
starting_index_find = string.find("old")
starting_index_rfind = string.rfind("old")
print(max(starting_index_rfind, starting_index_rfind))
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариант 1:

```
string = str(input())
starting_index_find = string.find("old")
starting_index_rfind = string.rfind("old")
if string.find("old") > string.rfind("old"):
    print(starting_index_find)
else:
    print(starting_index_rfind)
```